# Completar serie de tiempo (días) en datos de un DataFrame agrupados por group by

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

Tengo el siguiente Dataframe, con el nombre Datos : 
[image: DataFrame con datos sim agrupar]

Apliqué df.groupby('site') para clasificar los datos por esta característica. 
Luego de clasificarla quiero completar, para todos los registros, la columna "date" día por día.

```
grouped = Datos.groupby('site')
```

El procedimiento que pienso debo seguir será:
1. Generar una secuencia de completa entre fecha de inicio y fecha final. (Paso completado).

```
for site in grouped:
        dates = ['2018-01-01', '2020-01-17']
        #dates = [grouped.date]
        startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime( dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d") 
        endDate   = datetime.datetime.strptime( dates[-1],"%Y-%m-%d") 
        days = (endDate - startDate).days  # how many days between?
        allDates = {datetime.datetime.strftime(startDate+datetime.timedelta(days=k), 
                                        "%Y-%m-%d"):0 for k in range(days+1)}
```

2. Comparar esta secuencia con la columna 'date' de mis groupby.('site') y añadir aquellas que no estén presentes no coincidan con las fechas en 'date'.
3. Escribir una función o bucle que permita actualizar la columna 'date' con las nuevas fechas y además que complete los valores faltantes con 0. Para ello usaré:

```
(grouped.apply(agregar_dias))
```

Hasta los momentos he logrado sólo la completar el paso 1, por lo que les solicito su ayuda y conocimientos para completar los pasos 2 y 3. 
Mucho sabría agradecer su siempre importante ayuda. 
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer algo asi:

Creamos unos datos de prueba:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-02-01','2018-02-05','2018-02-09' ], 'total_volume': [1000, 2000, 2500], 'days_passed':[1, 5, 9]})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df


    date    total_volume    days_passed
0   2018-02-01  1000    1
1   2018-02-05  2000    5
2   2018-02-09  2500    9
```

1) Partiendo de un dataframe similar creamos una serie de fechas a partir de una fecha maxima y minima:

```
r = pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max())
r

DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-01', '2018-02-02', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-04',
               '2018-02-05', '2018-02-06', '2018-02-07', '2018-02-08',
               '2018-02-09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

2) Usamos ese rango con el dataframe de partida:

```
df2 = df.set_index('date').reindex(r).fillna(0.0).rename_axis('date').reset_index()
df2

    date    total_volume    days_passed
0   2018-02-01  1000.0  1.0
1   2018-02-02  0.0 0.0
2   2018-02-03  0.0 0.0
3   2018-02-04  0.0 0.0
4   2018-02-05  2000.0  5.0
5   2018-02-06  0.0 0.0
6   2018-02-07  0.0 0.0
7   2018-02-08  0.0 0.0
8   2018-02-09  2500.0  9.0
```

Lo que hemos hecho es usar las fechas como indice para el df de partida, con lo que nos ha expandido las filas. Al indicar `.fillna(0.0)`, las filas extras nos las rellena con 0s como necesitabas en lugar de `NaN`. Y ya por ultimo, volvemos a colocar 'Date' como columna.

Comment: Agradecido por la recomendación TitoOrt. Sólo aclaro que hice el group by por la columna 'site' porque cada a site le falta un intervalo de fechas en específico. Al tomar sólo las fechas como sugieres, la completación no lo hará para cada 'site' sino que lo tomará los días, sin importar el  'site' . 
Es decir si al site=A le falta la fecha '2019-12-25' y el site='B' cuenta con registros para ese día, al considerar sólo la columna 'date' no completaría las fechas para la tienda 'A'

Comment: Si, deberias hacer la operacion para cada grupo.

Comment: son 104 grupos, por eso buscaba una solución con mayor optimización